# stream video from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, video-streaming

I have some video files in iPhone library and I am developing iPhone app to stream video from my iPhone to another device.

I have already server developed at iPhone side.

My question is how can I stream this video files to another device or server from iPhone.

Another question is I have done video segment by apples mediafilesegmenter and generate ts and m3u8 files.I am wondering what is different between if I give link to m3u8 file(which is called http streaming may be) or link to the direct video file (mov,mp4) to the renderer.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code I have given in [Writing an app to stream video to iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978405/writing-an-app-to-stream-video-to-iphone/8937518#8937518) to stream the video.  However the video should be converted using the metadata mover  and it should be compatible of playing in iPhone You can use mirovideo converter to do this.