# ios 5 - how to play video with a web url

Tags: ios, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

i want to play a video on the link: www.mysite.com/iphone/video.mp4

i use ios5 and MPMoviePlayerController i tried with the following code but it only shows a black page:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/iphone/video.mp4"]];                                               [[player view] setFrame:[self.view.bounds]];                                                                                       [self.view addSubview:[player view]]; [player play];
```

is it possible to play a video by the web url string? i have many videos so i dont want to put them in my project so i need to play it from web

@Edit: I done it with the example on the [apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html)

it uses stream but solves my problem because i use a web url. thanks for all answers

Comment: Check video exist or not on URL you are fetching from

Comment: i try with the url : http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov but not playing

Comment: Hi ercan, have u got the solution b'cos i m facing same problem(unable to play video using web url).If u got answer then please share which is useful for us.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3idiots.mov" ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400);  
    [moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: my problem is playing a mov or mp4 file from web url. my video is not inside of my project so i think the bundle is not my solution. but i try your code hopelessly it crashes and the error says: [NSURL initFileUrlWithPath:] : nil string parameter. i only change the pathForResource parameter from your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the streaming server up and ready, it is quite easy to implement a video controller that pops up youtube-style.

[Writing an app to stream video to iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978405/writing-an-app-to-stream-video-to-iphone)

Comment: hi, we dont have streaming server so is it impossible to play a video from a link? we have only a simple windows hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3idiots.mov" ofType:nil];
```

Pass url like thislike this,

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/v/HGd9qAfpZio&hl=en_US&fs=1&"];
```

Comment: :( unfortunately it doesnt work too :(. did anyone try and get success with this? or am i trying an impossible thing?

Comment: What the heck is that video you linked to? :O

Comment: This is not a helpful answer. It is joke, i believe.