# How to play a local video using MPMoviePlayerController after the video was saved to photo album

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];


    //get the videoURL 
    NSString *tempFilePath = [videoURL path];


    if ( UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath))
    {
      // Copy it to the camera roll.
      UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), tempFilePath);
    } 



    //NSURL *movieUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    _videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    _videoPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(kMarginWidth, kMarginWidth, kMPlayerWidth, kMPlayerHeight);

    // Here is where you set the control Style like fullscreen or embedded
    _videoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    _videoPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    _videoPlayer.contentURL = videoURL; 

     self addSubview:_videoPlayer];

}
```

---

but videoPlayer does not woks,  the only shows "loading movie" on the screen for seconds.

so could some 1 tell me how to play the saved video?  or how to retrieve the path of saved video in album?

Comment: I saw your similar question in other stackoverflow link..  Use the following code to play the video and check..  Hope this will be useful..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978405/writing-an-app-to-stream-video-to-iphone/8937518#8937518

Comment: I finally find the problem, it is caused by the animation.

Comment: ohh still MPMoviePlayerController will consume more memory..  Please check it.  You can post you solution to the problem as a answer so that it will help some one in future.. thanks..