# Video live streaming from Windows to iOS device using bluetooth

Tags: ios, windows, video, bluetooth

I've had a bit of a look around on this forum, and it seems that I there are fairly non specific answers to this question: 
If I am capturing a video on a Windows machine, say a webcam (in my case it'll be an industrial camera), and I want to display in RT (or as close to) the video on an iPad, what protocols/frameworks should I use.
Personally, I would have thought that Bluetooth would be an easy option (I've dealt with bluetooth chips in the past in embedded projects, using them as a virtual serial connection) but I cannot seem to find anyone who has documented their use of iOS bluetooth in this manner.
The core bluetooth option seems to be what apple is pushing, but I don't think this is the way we need to go.

I can easily code a encoder/de-coder for bitmaps sent as a data stream, and continually render them to screen, but I'm unsure if (a) it's easy to set this up, and (b) if there is an easier way to stream video between two devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to stream your video via CoreBluetooth. Even tough Apple officially allows larger MTUs in IOS 7, the bandwidth is still much too small.

With classic bluetooth (3.0) an IOS device can only connect to MFi compliant devices, which I'm sure your Windows PC is not.

I think the way you should go is to use some WiFi-streaming-server-solution. First google result brought up http://www.wikihow.com/Stream-Your-Webcam which uses VLC for that. You should be able to grab this stream via WiFi in IOS as explained here: [Writing an app to stream video to iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978405/writing-an-app-to-stream-video-to-iphone)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Contacted apple dev support, didn't get much out of them. I'm moving it onto Wifi option now.

Comment: Ended up using the Wifi option. Setting up a TCP socket using [link](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)