# Real time video stream to iPad application

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, real-time

I'm essentially working as a junior software engineer and I've been tasked with creating an iPad application that is capable of receiving a real-time stream from a UAV. The camera hardware hasn't been determined so I need to put a spec together so that it can be used in my iOS app.

However I feel like I'm massively inexperienced to do so as I don't have much of an understanding about media streaming and experience writing iOS apps to produce a decoder to play the video data - I started with Obj-C about 4 months ago when I joined the company.

I apologise if this isn't the best outlet for such a request but could anyone shed some light on the process of receiving low latency video streams or is it far beyond my current ability?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to play the video you are receiving or do any playback operations, this should be what you are looking for: [Writing an app to stream video to iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978405/writing-an-app-to-stream-video-to-iphone)

You can also record the video, [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html) from apple

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll take a look at that. I've come across a few different solutions but my application needs to be as real-time as possible (sub 300ms)